# How do we split the Date in the path?

Tags: java

we have the path and it contains like `"/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/2015-11-25/"`.
Sometimes the folder is increasing recursively.
How do we split the date alone in java, we have to pass the path in the SQL without using the date.

Required path is :`/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/`

Comment: "Sometimes the folder is increasing recursively." - What does that mean?

Comment: You can use regex and define the format for the date you've been searching for

Comment: So paths like `/folder1/folder2/` etc., i.e. without the date, are possible as well or is the date always present? And is the date always the last part or could there be paths like `/folder1/folder2/2017-03-22/folder3/`?

Comment: @Thomas - Date will be appended at the last only.

Comment: @Fildor - It means for example 1 - /folder1/2015-10-10                  example-2 - /folder1/folder2/2015-10-10                                         example-3 - /folder1/folder2/folder3/2015-10-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the path as a string and use a simple `replaceAll()` on it

```
String s = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/2015-11-25/";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}/", ""));
```

Comment: Do you have any idea, if we have the hour with minute in the same date. For Example /2015-10-10 03:30

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\/?` to replace the date

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Z784AC/2)

```
String line = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/2015-11-25/";
line = line.replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\/?", "");
```

Output

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/
```

---

**EDIT**

If you have hour and minute in the same date, then you can use this code

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}(?:\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})?\\/?", "");
```

Infact you can replace the above code with this edited one. It will deal with both the cases. See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/JiXxGM/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Do you have any idea, if we have the hour with minute in the same date. For Example /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/2015-10-10 03:30

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham yes we can modify our `regex` to deal with both the cases. See EDIT of my answer.

Comment: Really it is very helpful.Thansk a lot

Comment: If we have only hour in the string how do we construct -                   
 1.String line = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/dt=2015-11-25/hour=05"; 2.String line = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/dt=2015-11-25/hour=05\min=00";